# Installing zsh from source file without root user access

Tags: zsh, software-installation, make

I clone the source of *zsh* source file from github, after that I ran the command

```bsh
bash install-sh
```

and

```
./install
```

It prompt to me that

> No input file specified
> .

Then follow the instructions I tried

```
make install
```

No luck
I got

> *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Can anyone give me some Hints or Instructions?

Comment: Did you read the `INSTALL` document in the repository?  It starts by saying to run the `configure` script. You may want to do that, but with the `--help` option to read more about how `configure --prefix=pathname` works (which is also mentioned in the `INSTALL` document).

Comment: If you ran `configure`, then `make` would not complain with `No rule to make target 'install'. Stop`.

Comment: It seems that the problems is :there is no such file whose name is configure. So even if I did run the command "./configure", it yells back that "No such file or directory"

Comment: So, according to `INSTALL`, you should then first run `./Util/preconfig`.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that I really missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zsh` shell is most likely available pre-compiled as a package through your system's package management software.

The official source distribution of the `zsh` shell, found at, e.g., https://www.zsh.org/pub/, contains a `configure` script.  The Git repository is primarily for developers, and people wanting to contribute to the `zsh` project. It lacks the `configure` script used for configuring things like the project's installation prefix and for creating the actual Makefile(s) that `make` would later use to build the software. It lacks the script since it is derived from the rest of the code in the repository.

According to the project's `INSTALL` file, one needs to run `./Util/preconfig` from the top-level directory of the repository first to create the `configure` file.  A pre-configuration step similar to this is relatively common in projects where a `configure` script (or equivalent) is not distributed in the project's source code repository.

Once that has been done, you may run `configure` with its `--prefix` option to point to a local directory such as `"$HOME"/local` or similar where you want the project to install when you later run `make install`.  The `make` utility will automatically create `bin` and other directories under the chosen installation prefix.

Also, don't forget to add the installation prefix's `bin` directory to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: `configure` is shipped with the source distribution. But is not included in the source repository. You'd generally clone the source repository if you intend to contribute to the code (or if you want to live on the bleeding edge and use features that have not been released yet). As `configured` is generated from other files, it doesn't make sense to include it in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to install to system directories, which (quite consistently) you can't as unprivileged user (that's the whole idea).

So, change that installation target directory!

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/INSTALL is your reference.

the `configure` script comes with a help command:

`./configure --help` will tell you you can change the installation prefix.

This is simply done using `./configure --prefix=/home/ren/prefix`, assuming there's a directory `/home/ren/prefix` that you want to install things into.

Then, you just continue normally. You will have to, afterwards, tell your system that there's executables you want to use in `/home/ren/prefix/bin`, i.e. `export PATH=/home/ren/prefix/bin:$PATH`. You also need to tell it that there's libraries, for example in `/home/ren/prefix/lib64` (you need to check that path yourself); `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ren/prefix/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Afterwards, you can just run your freshly compiled zsh:

```
$> zsh
```

yay!

Generally, I think compiling your shells on your own system should not be high on your priority list. You can install that using your package manager, much more sanely. If you just want to try things out, you can use `podman` or `docker` (just replace podman with docker in that case) to just try to run *containers*, in which **you** are root, without being root on the system.

```
podman run -it --rm debian:11
root@abcdef123:/# apt update
root@abcdef123:/# apt install -y zsh
root@abcdef123:/# zsh
abcdef123:/# ## this is now zsh
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your wisdom!

Comment: you're welcome, but if it's helpful, I'd rather see my answer get an upvote - that's how other users know it is something worth reading.